# Create copies of specific sheets into separate spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have searched all across the internet and can't seem to come up with a solution to this. Right now i am just using a script to make a copy of the entire spreadsheet and moving the spreadsheet. The spreadsheet has around 10 sheets, but I don't want to make a copy of the entire spreadsheet, I only want to duplicate three specific sheets, and each of these sheets would ideally be it's own spreadsheet.

I will need to set-up a trigger to run this script every day at 11:00 AM. So every day I would have a back-up of these three sheets.

Here is the code I am currently using. It just duplicates the entire spreadsheet. I can't see how I would be able to achieve what I mentioned above. Is something like that even possible?

I looked into trying to duplicate the entire spreadsheet three times, and then just deleting the sheets I didn't want from the duplicate. But i can't seem to figure out how to delete sheets from the duplicated file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```
function duplicateSheet(parameters) {
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5", "yyyy-MM-dd");
  var name = formattedDate + " Daily Manager's Conference Call";
  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("Folder ID");
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId())
  file.makeCopy(name, destination);
}
```

Comment: So what sheets/tabs do you want to copy?

Comment: @Cooper The tabs in the sheet are: Windsor, Barrie, Ottawa, Kingston, Toronto, Oshawa, Kitchener. I only want to copy Ottawa, Kingston & Toronto.

Comment: Okay thanks but I'm writing it so it can be anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Copying multiple sheets to individual spreadsheets**

To use this function all you need to do is provide it with an array of the file names that you want to copy to new spreadsheet.  I can change the input parameters to fit your needs.  Just let me know what you would like.

```
function copySheetsToSpreadsheets(sheetNameArray) {
  var sheetNameArray=sheetNameArray||["Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3"];
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var des=DriveApp.getFolderById("Destination Folder Id");
  for(var i=0;i<sheetNameArray.length;i++) {
    var ssFileName=Utilities.formatString('DailyManagersConferenceCall-%s-%s',sheetNameArray[i],Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT-5","yyyy-MM-dd"));
    var file=SpreadsheetApp.create(ssFileName);
    var f=DriveApp.getFileById(file.getId());
    var fi=f.makeCopy(f.getName(), des);
    var newss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(fi.getId());
    var sh=ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameArray[i])
    var newsh=sh.copyTo(newss);
    newss.deleteSheet(newss.getSheets()[0]);
    newsh.setName(sheetNameArray[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much Cooper this is perfect. Edit: Not sure how to mark my question as answered

Comment: There's a grey check mark to the left of every answer.  Click on the grey checkmark next to the answer you wish to select and it turns green.  Sorry, I had to do some searching because I haven't asked a question for a while.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet) to copy a single sheet to another spreadsheet, like this:

```
var sheetToCopy = oldSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("your_sheet_name");
var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("new_spreadsheet");
sheetToCopy.copyTo(newSpreadsheet);
```

And if you want to copy the spreadsheet to a certain folder, you can use:

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId());
DriveApp.getFolderById('your_folder_id').addFile(file);
```

Comment: This is great thank you. Is there a way to automatically place the new spreadsheet in a specific folder?

i.e.
"Ottawa" sheet to be copied and moved to folder MyDrive\Ottawa
"Toronto" sheet to be copied and moved to folder MyDrive\Toronto
"Kingston" sheet to be copied and moved to folder MyDrive\Kingston

Comment: Updated my answer with a sample of how to copy a file to another folder.